# Legend handle not correctly aligned in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm plotting 3 things at once: a multicolored line via a `LineCollection` (following [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)) and a `scatter` (for the markers to "cover" where the lines are joining) for an average value, and a `fill_between` for min/max. I get all the legend returns to plot a single legend handle. The graph looks like this:
[image: unaligned legend handle]

As one can note, the circle marker is not aligned with the line. How can I adjust this?

The piece of the code that is plotting them and the legend looks like:

```
      lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='turbo',zorder=3)
      p1 = ax.add_collection(lc)
      p2 = ax.fill_between(x, errmin,errmax, color=colors[1],zorder=2)
      ps = ax.scatter(x,y,marker='o',s=1,c=y,cmap='turbo',zorder=4)
      ax.legend([(p2, p1, ps)], ["(min/avg/max)"],fontsize=tinyfont, facecolor='white', loc='lower right')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend has a parameter [`scatteryoffsets=`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) which defaults to `[0.375, 0.5, 0.3125]`. As only one point is shown, setting it to `[0.5]` should show the dot in the center of the legend marker.

To change the color of the line in the legend, one could create a copy of the existing line, change its color and create the legend with that copy.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

x = np.arange(150)
y = np.random.randn(150).cumsum()
y -= y.min()
y /= y.max()
errmin = 0
errmax = 1
segments = np.array([x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:]]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='turbo', zorder=3)
lc.set_array(y[:-1])
p1 = ax.add_collection(lc)
p2 = ax.fill_between(x, errmin, errmax, color='lightblue', zorder=2, alpha=0.4)
ps = ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=5, color='black', zorder=4)
p1copy = copy(p1)
p1copy.set_color('crimson')
leg = ax.legend([(p2, p1copy, ps)], ["(min/avg/max)"], fontsize=10, facecolor='white', loc='lower right',
                scatteryoffsets=[0.5])
ax.margins(x=0.02)
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with scatter dot superimposed on line]

Comment: That is perfect! So simple, and yet I couldn't find it... thank you so much!

Comment: Since we are here, a small add-on question: do you know if there is a simple way to change the color of the line p1 on the handle?

Comment: I updated the code taking a copy of p1 and changing its color.

Comment: Worked as a charm! Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: sorry to bother again: I'm trying now to increase the size of the blue box in the handle (p2, from the fill_between). I've tried to use `handleheight=2.0`, (it takes only 1 value), and indeed increases the box, but de-aligns the rest. I also tried  `handler_map={p2: HandlerPolyCollection(ypad=2.0)}`, but that doesn't seem to affect the box.

Comment: I presume all heights go together with the fontsize.  Maybe you could try `leg = ax.legend(...., fontsize=15)` and then `leg.texts[0].set_fontsize(8)`?

Comment: It kind of worked, but also increased sideways. I wanted to increase the height to use a multi-line legend: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kceb8v6o7oit2f3/leg.png?dl=0.

Comment: You could create it with a shorter text. And afterwards use ...set_fontsize and ...set_text

Comment: Doesn't work either - I created with "." and is still large. Anyway, I'll use the original one (on the question), it's already quite good. Thank you for the help!